# How to get logging information if device freezes / hangs?

Tags: logging

I have written an app and on some devices, using the app freezes the system. My main problem is, that I do not get any log information, because as soon as the device is frozen, logging completely stops and obviously the crash-reports normally would be generated after the crash, which does not work, because the device is frozen.

I have attached the device to my laptop via adb (via USB) and logcat everything, but the logging just stops as the device freezes. I have also checked all possible log locations (I used [this reference](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26340/is-there-a-good-way-to-find-out-why-an-android-phone-hangs%22%5Dthis%20reference)) and could not find anything.

Since the app crashes only on about 10% of all devices (the devices are identical and have the same firmware) I need to test the app on the device and cannot use the emulator. However if the app crashes, I can relieable reproduce the crash using adb monkey. On the other 90% adb monkey won't crash the device.

Is there anything else I can log / test / check? Is there a way to get a memory dump, once the device is frozen?

Although I don't think this is relevant: The device is a XORO 9718DR tablet and the device is rooted. The app is written by myself and not available in the market. It mainly uses only Buttons, TextView, ImageView, HttpClientConnection, Threads, AsyncTasks and other "normal" Android stuff. It even does not use the webview.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write to a log in permanent storage on almost any device that you create an app for, echoing each line of your executing code to that storage. That way if the device hangs, you can read your log on reboot and see what the last statement is. You could have a function to automatically upload any log files to your server and then delete it from the device, which executes when the app starts. So that no matter what happens, you always have a record of the last line that executed.

Comment: I used the log recorder from the [androidlogcatviewer Project](https://code.google.com/p/androidlogcatviewer/) and had no success (the logfiles stops at the same position as the adb output, which I capture via USB).

Comment: I also had no success using the debugger. The idea was that I could see the position of my app when the device hangs. However when the device hangs the debugger only says "Device disconnected".